# Hibernate: problem with entity manager factory

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to understand Hibernate and JPA but I'm stuck here (I'm working with NetBeans with a Mac, if it can be useful).
This is my code:

```
package test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 *
 * @author Miky
 */
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "test.Person[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

This is a dummy class, it doesn't mind that it doesn't do nothing.
The main is:

```
package test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 *
 * @author Miky
 */
public class Main {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "testPU";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(1);
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(p);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
    }
}
```

The persistence file (that is automatically generated by netbeans in the META-INF package) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>test.Person</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackoverflow?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="leonida95."/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The errors I get are:

```
    mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence logDeprecation
WARN: HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: testPU
    ...]
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stackoverflow?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull]
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
mar 06, 2019 3:48:05 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:73)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3556)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.buildCollationMapping(ConnectionImpl.java:1007)
    ... 34 more
Java Result: 1
```

reading other questions I didn't find any useful answer. I already added the following libraries:

That are the Hibernate ones and the ones about MySQL driver and connector. Moreover I added these libraries [libraries in the Compile Libraries section] and these [libraries in the Run Libraries section] (Probably I added too many things, but I right now I'm quite confused). Any tips?

EDIT
changing from int to Long doesn't resolve the problem. The problem is partially resolved with it and removing some outdating libraries. Right now the code work but it doesn't stop running and continue to ramain stuck forever. (i had to remove the images, otherwise i can't edit)

Comment: Try changing `id` type to `Long`

Comment: It was Long originally. It doesn't work either. I edit my post with thecode with Long (and error)

Comment: no. This solve a part of the problem but not the whole one. Right now the code work, with long instead of int and without outdated libraries. The problem right now is that the code run forever. I modify the class "Person" with more field and the code create the table person and add p to it, but then it remains stuck.

Comment: The error in the stacktrace is from using an outdated MySQL Connector/J. Which version are you using? And if you fixed that and you are now confronted with a different problem, then ask a new question. Don't make your question a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

One of your mysql connector is really old (version 5.1.23).

You need only one connector but you have two (5.1.23 and 8.0.15)

Try to use newer connector with 8.0.15 version and remove 5.1.23 from classpath

Comment: I have to remove MySQL JDBC .... connector 5.1.23 from the everywhere?

Comment: yes, you need only one version of connector and it should be 8.0.15

Comment: ok I do it. Now the code continue to output errors but the database is created.
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: test.Person
and it doesn't stop running.

Comment: Moreover, the table is created but the first line isn't written (it should be the person p I added, right? with the first id and nothing else, i suppose). Only the table is created (empty) and the code run forever

Comment: You strategy for generation of id - is autogenerated id. But you also set id manually. (See, person.setId(1) ). You need to remove this line if you want autogeneration ids. If you want manually assign IDs - remove @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) on id field in Person class.